# Passing pointers to private structs in C?

Tags: c, gcc, struct, typedef, forward-declaration

How can I pass around pointers to structs which have private definitions, without prepending the pointer types with `struct`?

For example this works:

```
typedef struct Handle {
    Ino ino;
} Handle;

bool handle_open(Handle **);
```

But if I move the struct definition into a source file, other source files are forced to use `struct Handle *`, instead of `Handle *`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `typedef struct Handle Handle;`. In this case, `Handle` is an incomplete type (just like `struct Handle`).

Comment: This seems to work fine. However I get errors if the typedef is done to the same type more than once. Kind of annoying, still trying it out.

Comment: oh. I get it. as in, if you do `typedef struct Handle Handle; typedef struct Handle Handle;`? There's an error because you're defining the typedef `Handle` twice. If it occurs in a header file, please use include guards.

Answer (score 2):

This should go fine in a header:

```
struct _Handle;
typedef struct _Handle Handle;
```

Then you can put the actual definition of `_Handle` in the body of the file that actually manipulates the struct.

Comment: your second line would be sufficient. it forward declares the `struct` as well.

Answer (score 0):

> if I move the struct definition into a source file, other source files are forced to use struct Handle *, instead of Handle *

Then `typedef` the pointer, instead of (or in addition to) the struct.

Comment: `typedef`-ing pointer types isn't usually a good idea, and it's not necessary here.

Comment: It's a fine idea when the calling code is only supposed to get pointers to whatever and they don't need to know it's a pointer (both of which are implied by the name 'Handle'). Last I checked, it was a good enough idea for Win32 (e.g. HWND)

Comment: Many things are "good enough" for Windows. In fact Windows has "good enough" written all over it.